# Recursive Select in Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, recursion

I have a class Activity that can have several activities associated with it (List). How can I configure my class with Fluent API to load all other child activities if one parent activity is selected?
Here is my Domain Class for Activity:

```
public class Activity : ProjectBase
{
    private string activityType;

    public string ActivityType
    {
        get { return activityType; }
        set { activityType = value; }
    }


    private string catagory;

    public string Catagory
    {
        get { return catagory; }
        set { catagory = value; }
    }


    private string priority;

    public string Priority
    {
        get { return priority; }
        set { priority = value; }
    }



    public Activity()
        :base()
    {

    }
}
```

ProjectBase has the List property declared. My database is generated following Table Per Hierarchy and the table for Activity seems generated fine for recursion.
Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was put virtual on the list and it brought all related records:

```
    private List<Activity> activities = new List<Activity>();

    public virtual List<Activity> Activities
    {
        get { return activities; }
        set { activities = value; }
    }
```

Thanks for the help people!